Defining and calling variables in shell script using sed steps
I have an HTML file that lays out images of text to create interesting typographic patterns. The images are placed in the local web page with
<img src="[path-to-project-folder]/DIR/[filename].png">.

The project folder has 15 folders with variations of all the images in them, named 001, 002 etc. I want to replace DIR with a random number from 001-015 and have tried the following in a shell script to get sed to replace the variable number in steps across my source file;
for RUN in {1..15};
do 
var1=`shuf -i 001-015 -n 1`
step=$((step + 1));
while [ ${#var1} -ne 3 ];
 do
   var1="0"$var1
 done

echo $var1
echo $step

sed  -i -e "s/DIR/$var1/"{100..1..$step} temp.htm
done

Unfortunately that results in an error of
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'

I know from attempting to debug that $var1 is replaced okay. It is $step that is not getting through. I have tried things like ${step} and combinations of backslashes but that's just copying other scripts that work rather than truly understanding what is going on after my sed s/// argument to explain the error. The expansion section in the bash manual doesn't seem to explain the sed error.
Can anyone help please? I'd like the output to be random like
<img src="[path-to-project-folder]/001/[filename].png"><img src="[path-to-project-folder]/014/[filename].png"><img src="[path-to-project-folder]/003/[filename].png">.

and so on. I'm using sed 4.4 on Ubuntu 18.10 with bash 4.4.20

Brace expansion is done before variable substitution, so using a variable in a brace expression won't work (see "How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?" and its many duplicates). That said... what are you trying to accomplish with the $step and the brace expansion part of the sed command? I can't figure out what you're trying to get it to do.

@GordonDavisson what I did before was have 15 lines like this
sed -i '-es/DIR/015/'{100..1..15} temp.htm
with the 015 and 15 decreasing on each line down to 001/1. That allowed DIR to be renamed 015 every 15th time it appears, and then the next DIR to be renamed 014 every 14th time it appears and so on.
I could see patterns in the visual output that I want to pseudo-randomise with $var1 and the brace seemed to allow the sequential replacement.

@Fravadona - I'm working with really simple HTML though, back in the text-file era rather than today's megacomplex stuff. That aside, yes you understand correctly. So SED has always worked well for me with the s/[pattern]/[replacement]/g feature to replace a pattern globally really fast. But what I want to do now is replace a pattern every nth time. In this case to rename the DIR part of the src attribute to a three digit number that corresponds to my folder structure

in comments you mention sed -i '-es/DIR/015/'{100..1..15} but in your code you use sed -i -e "s/DIR/$var1/"; '-es/.../.../' is not the same as -e 's/.../.../', with the latter actually generating an error in this case; please review the question for accuracy of the code posted in the question

have you tried enabling debug mode (set -xv) and then run the script? review the output to see what sed sees when you try running sed -e 's/DIR/15/'{100..1..$step}

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

{100..1..$step} does not do what you think it does.
From the bash man page:

Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words. There are seven kinds of expansion performed: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion.
The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion.

Notice that brace expansion happens before parameter expansion.
The literal sequence of characters $step is not a valid number (increment), so the brace expansion fails.
Consider:
$ step=1
$ echo "preamble"{10..1..$step}
preamble{10..1..1}
$

shellcheck can provide useful diagnostics. It finds the problem in your code and reports:
sed  -i -e "s/DIR/$var1/"{100..1..$step} temp.htm
                         ^-------------^ SC2051 (warning): Bash doesn't support variables in brace range expansions.


A quick rewrite of your code:
for ((step=1; step<=15; step++)); do

    printf -v var1 '%03d' $(( (RANDOM%15)+1 ))

    echo $var1
    echo $step

    for (( n=100; n>=1; n-=step )); do
        echo "s/DIR/$var1/$n"
    done |
    sed  -i -f - temp.htm

done


Thanks @jhnc I think that has illuminated the source of the error message for me. Is there a way to call $step as a number in the brace? I could get
sed -i '-es/DIR/015/'{100..1..15} temp.htm
to work but I had to copy it and decrease the numbers each time, and the output had obvious patterns that I want to try and pseudo-randomise.

@JamesDavies the sample code replicates what I understand to be the intent of your code. You could probably safely use an eval to force brace expansion but generally eval is a bad idea.

that certainly runs without an error and displays the values of $var1 and $step, but when I tested it the resulting temp.htm file just wrote the first value of $dir. Then I realised I needed to start with 15 and decrease it to 1, rather than increase it from 1 to 15.
Changing the first line to for ((step=15; step>0; step--)); do seems to work! Thank you for your help.

@larsks I'm assuming there are a couple of people who really don't want this question to exist given that everything has been downvoted and not just your answer
